# Java Service Wrapper cannot find main class

Tags: java

Java Service Wrapper is the tools I need to run as a Windows service but came into a problem with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

My default command line is: java -jar software.jar

I have update the `wrapper.conf` for running `software.jar` located in D:\ and there was an error, the changes I have made:

```
# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../software.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar
```

and what should I put for this parameter? If I comment out, it would use `Main` class

```
wrapper.java.mainclass=software
```

As I declare "software" as the main class, I got the dread error:

```
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xsocket/connection/IHandler
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xsocket.connection.I
Handler
jvm 1    |      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
jvm 1    |      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)

jvm 1    |      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
jvm 1    | Could not find the main class: xSocketServer.  Program will exit.
wrapper  | JVM exited while loading the application.
jvm 1    | Exception in thread "main"
wrapper  | CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

My software.jar contains:

```
META-INF
org -- Eclipse setting
software.class
xsoftwareHandler.class
xSocket.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is to store all libraries in your `lib/` directory and then add the following information in your `wrapper.conf` file:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/*.jar
```

This way, the `Java Service Wrapper` will load all the `*.jar` file located in `../lib/` directory in the classpath, and you should not get this error again.

Of course, you can also define each JAR individually if you prefer:

```
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../software.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/xSocket.jar
...
```

Comment: Oh, I have an error after that and google for more information, thank to the other wrapper example, copied the jar into lib folder which make it work: http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=91554194

Answer (score 2):

As you are using an executable jar to normally launch your application.  You might want to try the WrapperJarApp helper class.  It is designed to help with integration of executable jars without requiring you to dig into the Manifest file for the main class name.   Take a look at this page for more information:
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html#method4

This has been available since version 3.3.3.

Cheers,
Leif

Comment: Hi, already solved but I couldn't get Windows service to run the jar since I did not create any code for the service like start, stop and restart. I got time out.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error does not seem to be with the Main class here. It seems to be with the "xSocket.jar" not being in the classpath.